# How to find the surface area of a pyramid in Java programming (CodeHS)?

Tags: java, calculator

I have an assignment on CodeHS to program a calculator for the surface area of a pyramid and it prints out the wrong surface area off by a few decimals. I don't see how this is incorrect (code below).

I've already tried plugging in the formula from Google for surface area and it did not work and printed the wrong number.

```
 public double surfaceArea() {
  double hw = (double)width/2;
  double hl = (double)length/2;
  double slantHeight1 = ((double)Math.sqrt( (double)height*height + 
   (double)hw*hw ));
  double slantHeight2 = ((double)Math.sqrt( (double)height*height + (double)hl*hl ));

  return (double)(((double)0.5 * 2 * slantHeight1 * width)
  + ((double)0.5 * 2 * slantHeight2 * length) 
  + (length * width));
```

Example: for a pyramid with length 1, width 3, and height 5 it is supposed to print 23.29 but it prints 23.69 and I don't know why?

Comment: What does your formula look like in a mathematical notation? When you do the calculation on a calculator with that formula, did it produce the correct result? If that's the case, you may have a programming problem that's on-topic for StackOverflow - if not, you're still stuck in the realm of mathematics which is not the topic of StackOverflow.

Comment: Also note - your code is incomplete - you need to post a [mcve] that we can compile and run. It's not clear where `width` and `height` come from and how they are declared.

Comment: But you may simply have a case of floating point inaccuracy - floating point calculations are not exact and every calculation introduces a certain amount of error from the exact result.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt it worked on a calculator. Width, height, length are part of the class Pyramid and then there is a separate tester class. They are private instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative solution: this is the equation for surface area of a right rectangular pyramid:

[image]

This can be simply written as:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double length = 1;
        double width = 3;
        double height = 5;
        double resultPyramidArea = (length * width) + (length * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width / 2, 2) +
                Math.pow(height, 2))) + (width * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(length / 2, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2)));

        System.out.println(resultPyramidArea);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
  return (double)(((double)0.5 * 2 * slantHeight1 * width)
  + ((double)0.5 * 2 * slantHeight2 * length) 
  + (length * width));
```

to this:

```
  return (double)(((double)0.5 * 2 * slantHeight1 * length)
  + ((double)0.5 * 2 * slantHeight2 * width) 
  + (length * width));
```

you got the formula wrong